# phantomjs and selenium - webdriver does not work

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

My selenium version is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to set the driver's port by the argument: `--webdriver`, like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities sCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, 
"/Users/user/phantomjs");
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "javascriptEnabled", true);
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "loadImages", true);
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "cookiesEnabled", true);

sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept-Language", "en");
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Connection", "keep-alive");

ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
cliArgsCap.add("--debug=true");
cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=127.0.0.1:36000");
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
PhantomJSDriver d = new PhantomJSDriver(sCaps);
```

but after I set the code like that, the console shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out 
waiting for driver server to start.
```

Isn't selenium able to handle the argument `--webdriver`?

Comment: Can you help me to understand what are you trying to do through `cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=127.0.0.1:36000");`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to fixed the port of GhostDriver

Comment: Then why are you taking `--webdriver` option ? Documentation clearly says `--webdriver starts in ‘Remote WebDriver mode’ (embedded GhostDriver): ‘[[:]]' (default '127.0.0.1:8910')` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download binary of phantomjs and then pass it to PhantomJSDriver.
In maven dependencies you are just using selenium not phantomjs

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Now add System.setPropertybefore driver instance

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); // not really needed: JS enabled by default
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:/phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

refer the link below for more info :-

http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/03/headless-browser-testing-using.html

use below code which is a way to set the port for PhantomJSDriver  :-

```
private void loadLightWeightDriverCustom() {
    ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PHANTOMJS_EXE.getAbsolutePath());
    cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
    cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
    cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
    capabilities.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(Configure(cliArgsCap), capabilities);
}

private PhantomJSDriverService Configure(ArrayList<String> cap) {
    return new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder().usingPhantomJSExecutable(PHANTOMJS_EXE)
            .usingPort(5555)
            .usingCommandLineArguments(
                    (cap.toArray(new String[cap.size()])))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I didn't paste all my code, I have set the phantomjs's path

Comment: I have added code which works fine with me.. try to use it and still does work then may be either your phantomjs binary is too old... download the new one

Comment: try to use cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=127.0.0.1:36000"); And my phantomjs's version is 2.1.1, Mac

Comment: why you're doing that .. if you want to hit local host on port 36000.. just use .get like :-   driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:36000/");

Comment: updated  my anwser .. Now I got that you want to change the port so I have found one solution .. mat it help you :)

Comment: I want to get the --webdriver-logfile work， Maybe I'm wrong